# Matlab: mirror results along xaxis

Tags: matlab

I can't seem to find any documentation explaining how to mirror my matlab results.

ie I have this:

[image]

and I want my results to be upside down....

using `set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse')` and `set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse'Y` do not work for me ( I am using figue and quiver to plot)

Comment: [Flipud](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) ?

Comment: Looks promising...will try it

Comment: I am getting wrong results

Comment: Can you give a bit of your code to have information and to help you?

Answer (score 3):

For display purposes, you can move the origin to the *upper left corner* via:

```
axis ij
```

By default when plotting it uses `axis xy`.  Excerpt from [axis documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html):

> `axis IJ`  puts MATLAB into its "matrix" axes mode.  The coordinate system origin is at the upper left corner.  The i axis is vertical and is numbered from top to bottom.  The j axis is horizontal and is numbered from left to right.
>
> `axis XY`  puts MATLAB into its default "Cartesian" axes mode.  The coordinate system origin is at the lower left corner.  The x axis is horizontal and is numbered from left to right.  The y axis is vertical and is numbered from bottom to top.

Comment: @LuisMendo Actually the answer mentions that `set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse')` does not work.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Oops, I read too fast. Still, `et(gca,'XDir','reverse')` does work for me...